# Use **kwargs both in function calling and definition

Tags: python

Suppose I have a function `get_data` which takes some number of keyword arguments. Is there some way I can do this

```
def get_data(arg1, **kwargs):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4

arg1 = 1
data['arg2'] = 2 
data['arg3'] = 3 
data['arg4'] = 4 

get_data(arg1, **data)
```

*So the idea is to avoid typing the argument names in both function calling and function definition. I call the function with a dictionary as argument and the keys of the dictionary become local variables of function and their values are the dictionary values*

I tried the above and got error saying `global name 'arg2' is not defined`. I understand I can change the `locals()` in the definition of `get_data` to get the desired behavior.

So my code would look like this

```
def get_data(arg1, kwargs):
    locals().update(kwargs)
    print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4

arg1 = 1
data['arg2'] = 2 
data['arg3'] = 3 
data['arg4'] = 4 

get_data(arg1, data)
```

and it wouldn't work too. Also cant I achieve the behavior without using `locals()`?

Comment: I suggest you check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Comment: Don't modify `locals`, it's not even guaranteed to work all the time: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals

Comment: .. why would you even do that? If you know arg2, arg3, arg4 are always going to be passed, then you should specify them as individual arguments. If you don't, then even if you had the desired behaviour, as soon as you referenced say `arg4` when `data` didn't define `arg4`, it would raise a NameError. It wouldn't even print any of the data, it would just raise an error.

Comment: @MorganWilde I understand this concept but the idea is to avoid writing names in function definition and function calling

Comment: lovesh, it's a bad concept to avoid names in function definition as it makes very hard to understand what arguments are required and what arguments have no effects.

Comment: @Vladimir But can it be done?

Comment: lovesh, what holds you from using `det_data(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4): ...` signature?

Comment: @Vladimir more keystrokes :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`**kwargs` is a plain dictionary. Try this:

```
def get_data(arg1, **kwargs):
    print arg1, kwargs['arg2'], kwargs['arg3'], kwargs['arg4']
```

Also, check documentation on [keyword arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).

Answer (score 4):

If we examine your example:

```
def get_data(arg1, **kwargs):
    print arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4
```

In your `get_data` functions's namespace, there is a variable named `arg1`, but there is no variable named `arg2`. so you can not reach a function or a variable that is not in your namespace.

In fact, in your namespace; there is a variable `arg1` and a `dictionary` object called `kwargs`. using `**` notation before the `kwargs` (name kwargs is not important in here, it can be something else too.) tells your python compiler that `kwargs` is a dictionary and all values in that dictionary will be evaluated as named parameters in your function definition.

Lets take a look at this example:

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    do something

myFunc(key1='mykey', key2=2)
```

when you call `myFunc` with named parameters `key1` and `key2`, your function definition acts like

```
def myFunc(key1=None, key2=None):
```

**but** with an exception! since `myFunc` have no named parameters, compiler do not know how to handle them directly since you can pass any named parameter to your function.

So your function accept those named parameters within a dictionary like  you call your function:

```
myFunc({key1:'mykey', key2:2})
```

so, your function definition get those parameters within a dictionary. `**kwargs` defines your dictionary in that point, which also tell compiler that any named parameters will be accepted (by the help of `**` signs before the kwargs)

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    print kwargs
```

will print

```
{key1:'mykey', key2:2}
```

So in your example, you can use `kwargs` like a dictionary;

```
def myFunc(**kwargs):
    kwargs['arg2']
    kwargs.get('arg3')
```

I hope it is not complicated (: