# Picking function to set:get values (and how to pass **kwargs)

Tags: python, pickle

I have a program that runs daily where there are a number of objects that a) take a while to create, b) are static for the day once they're built, so are good candidates to get pickled.

To avoid writing this a bunch of times:

```
if object_pickle_exists:
    obj = load_pickle_object
else:
    obj = run_some_function_to_build_object()
    pickle(obj) for later
```

I am instead trying to build a pickle-based function that I can generically use to "Get/Set" variables.

#### Loads Pickle, otherwise runs function and pickles it

```
def _dill(name, function_as_an_object, date = dt.date.today()):                                  
     try:
        with open('Pickles/'+name+'_'+date.strftime('%y-%b-%d'),'rb') as f:
            obj = pickle.load(f)
        return obj
    except FileNotFoundError:
        obj = function_as_an_object()
        with open('Pickles/'+name+'_'+date.strftime('%y-%b-%d'),'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(obj, f)
        return obj
```

Question 1) Is there a better way to do this / some existing package out there/

Question 2) I would like to add **kwargs to _dill(), but I'm not sure how to pass those kwargs down to the function_as_an_object:

```
    def _dill(name, function_as_an_object, date = dt.date.today(), **kwargs):                                  
        try:
            with open('Pickles/'+name+'_'+date.strftime('%y-%b-%d'),'rb') as f:
                obj = pickle.load(f)
            return obj
        except FileNotFoundError:
            obj = function_as_an_object(**kwargs) ??
            with open('Pickles/'+name+'_'+date.strftime('%y-%b-%d'),'wb') as f:
                pickle.dump(obj, f)
            return obj
```

Comment: You can find help with your Question 2 here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586888/use-kwargs-both-in-function-calling-and-definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Q1:

I am not a pickle or Clean Code expert myself, but I think that your way of handling an exception is a quite nice solution to this necessary check. Try/except blocks are ugly when used too extensively, but deliver a safety layer to your function. If you would like to check for a file without a try/except block, see this thread [on checking for files with the os module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-whether-a-file-exists-without-exceptions). I hope this helps.

Short Answer to Q2:

Your function signature is correct as is:

```
def _dill(name, function_as_an_object, date = dt.date.today(), **kwargs):
```

Moreover, your call to the `function_as_an_object` is technically correct. But depending on how the function is defined, you could cause an error, by passing too many, as little arguments or wrong data types.

Longer Answer to Q2:

Let me make a simple example:

```
def function_as_an_object(x, y):
    print("x =", x)
    print("y =", y)

def foo(function_as_an_object, **kwargs):
    function_as_an_object(**kwargs)

foo(function_as_an_object, x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

In this case, `foo` calls `function_as_an_object` with the keyword arguments, it has received. But this will result in an error because `function_as_an_object` only takes in **two** parameters.

Key word arguments in python return a dictionary with the given **names** as *keys* and the given **values** as *values*. Allow me to explain the following hypothetical function call of your `_dill` method:

```
_dill("filename", function_as_an_object, x="string value", y=20)
```

In the case shown above, the `x` and `y` arguments, are stored in a `kwargs` object, which is essentially a dictionary. You can access the values by iterating over the kwargs variable for example. See the [geeks for geeks tutorial on **kwargs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/) for more information. Now when you pass the `kwargs` to your function (`function_as_an_object(**kwargs)`) you are essentially passing the value of `x` (string) and `y` (integer) in this order to the function.

All in all, be aware of how many keyword arguments you pass, what you are doing with your `kwargs`. Otherwise, you can quickly run into errors.